# How to access Webdings OpenType font in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex

Is it possible to use the character set available in the "Webdings" OpenType font which is installed on my PC using XeLaTeX? Other non-symbol fonts seem to work fine, but I just get boxes for every character I try in this font, and other symbol fonts like Wingdings etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Webdings is not Unicode encoded. With such fonts `\char` often fails. You can use `\XeTeXglyph` instead (the whiledo-loop generate a tabular which shows you which values to use):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}%
\raggedright
\newcounter{glyphcount}
\setcounter{glyphcount}{0}
\font\myfont = "Webdings"

{char:  \myfont \char50}

{xetexglyph: \myfont \XeTeXglyph50}


\whiledo
{\value{glyphcount}<\XeTeXcountglyphs\myfont}
{\arabic{glyphcount}:~%
{\myfont\XeTeXglyph\arabic{glyphcount}}\quad
\stepcounter{glyphcount}}
\end{document}
```

See [XeTeX Reference Guide](http://ctan.org/pkg/xetexref) for `\XeTeXglyph` and `\XeTeXcountglyphs`.

Comment: Great answer. Could you add a link pointing to where things like `\XeTeXcountglyphs` and `\XeTeXglyph` are documented?