# Euclid Math One

Tags: fonts

My question is simple: can I use the EuclidMathOne font in LaTeX documents (in mathmode)?
There is a document prepared by my professor, and I want to use the same font. As far as I know, he used MathType, and that font is available there, however I could not yet find it in LaTeX.

Comment: If the font is OpenType and it's available in your system, then you can use `XeLaTeX`.

Comment: ...or `LuaLaTeX`.

Comment: Nope, its a symbol font and not Unicode encoded. You need a little bit more than just plugging it into XeLaTeX. You need to define\use spesific glyphs to get to the symbols.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, as suggested by the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The [Euclid font](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/fonts.htm) family from [Design Science](http://www.dessci.com/en/) (distributed with Math Type equation editor for Word) is a version of Computer Modern, the "standard" font in TeX.

You probably want `EuclidMathOne` for the calligraphic fonts. That you can obtain with `$\mathcal{ABC}$` in a Latex document with the default fonts.

Please note that Xe or LuaTeX is not a good option here,  `EuclidMathOne` is a symbol font and to use it for anything more than a single symbol  you need a proper support package to do anthing useful.  See the post [How to access Webdings OpenType font in XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37412/how-to-access-webdings-opentype-font-in-xelatex)