# Using Dingbats font in xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex

This must be a real-newbie-level question (which is kind of embarassing having used plain TeX to write my PhD thesis in 1992), but I am not be able to find an answer. Even if there are 5 millions similar questions here... so, my MWE is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\dingbatsfont{Dingbats}
\newcommand\ding[1]{{\dingbatsfont\symbol{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\ding{115} % no output
{\dingbatsfont ❤} % error --- comment out to have a PDF file 
\end{document}
```

...and running it with `xelatex` gives an error on the second line:

```
** WARNING ** 1 glyph names (out of 1) missing Unicode mapping.
** WARNING ** ToUnicode CMap "TZCCMX+Dingbats-UTF16" removed.
** ERROR ** pdf_ref_obj(): passed invalid object.
```

whilst if I remove it, I have no error, but the `\ding{115}` gives nothing. The strange thing is that the PDF file generated (when I remove the second line) seems to have the font loaded:

```
(0)samsung-romano:~/education/LibroEje/tmp% pdffonts lalla.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
IPQPDZ+Dingbats-Identity-H           CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
WPNUQB+LMRoman10-Regular-Identity-H  CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      7  0
```

...and the font is here and usable by LibreOffice:

[image: LibreOffice font selector]

I tried to substitute the `115` with the Unicode codepoint `"2773` but then I have the error above again.

What am I doing (terribly) wrong?

Comment: Without the actual font it is difficult to say. But you can try the method described here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37418/2388

Comment: Now it's strange. The suggestion *does* work on Linux, but does not work on windows... I mean, in Linux I can see all the gliphs of Dingbats, in windows I have the error above. Probably a font problem, so. The font is in a *.pfb file. Moreover, I tried to adapt the suggested example to fontspec (using `\newfontface\myfont{Dingbats}` instead of  `\font\myfonts="Dingbats"` but then I have an error on `\stepcounter`... (??)

Comment: The code is meant for opentype or ttf-fonts. If your font is a `.pfb` you should better create a tfm-file and use it "in the standard" way and not with fontspec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}% load it first
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

char: \ding{115}

\end{document}
```

There is also a TrueType dingbats font. For that one it makes sense to define an own `\ding`

Comment: Nice. Still stymied about why `pifont` doesn't work if you call it after fontspec, while my `\myding` (that should be the same) does.

Comment: By the way... which is the TTF dingbat font? Wingding? Thanks.

Comment: there are a lot ... For example: http://www.azfonts.net/download/zafdingn/ttf.html

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer. Most of merits should go to @Ulrike Fischer.

The problem is that I supposed that Type1 font could be treated the same way that opentype or ttf ones. The minimal snippet that works in `latex`, `pdflatex` (commenting out the `fontspec`, that is) and in `xelatex` is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % comment for pdflatex or latex
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myding}[1]{{\fontfamily{pzd}\fontencoding{U}%
  \fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont\char#1}}

{char:  \myding{115}}

\end{document}
```

...and both compilers produced the same symbol (a black filled triangle, similar to U+25B2). Probably there is a better way to achieve this, but I'm quite happy with this...

Comment: no need for a new command, see my answer.